# Use cell value as part of a reference to a cell range in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-2011

My problem is similar to that in this quesion: [Row in formula change based on value in another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091878/row-in-formula-change-based-on-value-in-another-cell), i.e. I want to use the value of a cell as reference to another cell in a formula of yet another cell.

However, I want the value of a cell to only be the *part of* a cell range. Let me give you an example:

A1 holds `worksheet-a`

In C1 I'd like to have a forumla that results in `=SUM('worksheet-a'!B:B)`

Based on the other question, I thought that something like `=SUM(INDIRECT(A1)&"!B:B")` might do it. Sadly, it does not.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works in this way

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1;"!B:B")))
```

or with ampersand

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A1&"!B:B"))
```

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped me drill down on the issue. Apparently the `-` within the worksheet name caused the problem. I could just avoid worksheet names with a minus.