# controlling a formula with the value from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

This is a very basic example.

What is in A3 and A4 are the formulas that are in B3 & B4 respectively.


I want the value in B4 to be "ValueB2"(the value from B2)

I basically want to control the formula in B4  with a value from another cell(C4)

Can this be done or how do I do it?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091878/row-in-formula-change-based-on-value-in-another-cell) might be what i am looking for?

Comment: @pnuts have corrected the image and yes that works tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("b",C4))
```

this in B4 works

Answer (score 0):

The INDIRECT function seems to be what you would want to use for this based on your description.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx

Comment: It would be better if you added the relevant information from your link to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just joined and that was my first answer. I didn't know that more detail was the standard.